# Checking to see if a charArray has only hex digits

Tags: c, hex, arrays

I have a program that accepts 16-bit hex values as inputs. What I want to do is to have it extract these values. For example, if I input:

*0xFFFF 0x0000 0x1234*

I'd like the program to iterate through this input string, and extract each hex value one at a time. Also, if the string is not in the correct 0x**** format, contains invalid characters such as $0x5544, or invalid hex digits such as 0x45GG, then I want the program to print out "Invalid input".

I currently have a pointer that I increment through each char, but I want to test the hex values to see if they are between allowed hex digits (0-F), which what I am not sure how to do

Comment: Well, I currently have a pointer that I increment through each char, but I want to test the hex values to see if they are between allowed hex digits (0-F), which what I am not sure how to do

Comment: Put that into your question.

Comment: use strtok and strtol.

Comment: "16-bit hex values" -- don't forget to check the result, then. Is `0x123` valid as well, or must it be entered as `0x0123`? Is `0xabcd` valid? (It usually is.)

Comment: Hint: `if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')) ...`

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions? A single hex value in that format should match to `"$0x[0-9A-F]{4}"` (Note: I am currently suffering from [this](http://xkcd.com/208/))

Comment: @Jongware I'm still debating on the first one, but as for 0xabcd, yes that is valid

Comment: I forgot another case edge: `0x001234` (where the result is still within 16-bit range). Reason for all of these is you should separate *input* and *range* checking. If your input is restricted to *exactly* 4 hex digits, then you cannot use `strtoul`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

bool isValid1(const char *s){
    unsigned long v;
    char *endp;
    errno = 0;
    v = strtoul(s, &endp, 16);
    return !*endp && v < 0x10000 && errno != ERANGE;
}

bool isValid2(const char *s){//limited to four HEX characters : 0xXXXX
    if(strlen(s)!=6)
        return false;
    return 
        *s == '0' && tolower(s[1])=='x' &&
        isxdigit(s[2]) && isxdigit(s[3]) && isxdigit(s[4]) && isxdigit(s[5]);
}

int main(void){
    char data[] = 
        "0xFFFF 0x0000 0x1234 0x01234 $0xFFFF 0x45GG 0x12345\n";
    char *p = data;
    for(p = strtok(p, " \n"); p ; p = strtok(NULL, " \n")){
        if(!isValid1(p))
            printf("isValid1(%s) : invalid input\n", p);
        if(!isValid2(p))
            printf("isValid2(%s) : invalid input\n", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux `isValid1("FFFF")` is true, `isValid2` is not valid format.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY This is good thanks! However, it is giving me an error: 'errno' undeclared and 'ERANGE' undeclared. Why is this?

Comment: @GBoggs `errno` & `ERNAGE` that should not be an error if reading the `errno.h`.